# Is it possible to modify intermediate model in ManyToManyField relation in Django?

Tags: django, manytomanyfield

Suppose I did something like the following to establish a many-to-many relationship between two models:

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publications = models.ManyToManyField(Publication)
```

Now I'd like to add some extra fields to the many-to-many relationship. I was looking for and I find I can do something like this:

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publications = models.ManyToManyField(Publication, through='Enrollment', through_fields=('article', 'publication'))

class Enrollment(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    publication = models.ForeignKey(Publication, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_joined = models.DateField(null=True, default=None, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['article', 'publication']]
```

but, is there a way to add some extra fields and preserve all previous relations?

Comment: No, or at least not easily. It might be better to first define it as a second m2m field, then make a data migration, and finally remove the old m2m field.

Comment: Why would it be any different than adding a field to a normal model?